# SurveyJS Angular2 Error

Tags: angular, surveyjs

I just added surveyjs to my angular 2 project and am getting a constant error in the console, no matter what I try.

The error I am getting is this.survey.doAfterRenderSurvey is not a function.

I think this is something built into surveyjs.  The only code I have for the component is:

```
Survey.Survey.cssType = "bootstrap";
var survey = new Survey.SurveyModel(this.surveyJSON);
Survey.SurveyNG.render("surveyElement", { model: survey });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your boilerplate? https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs_angular_quickstart repo works ok for me. Probably problem is in dependencies.

Comment: Can you post a link to your project or [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I was able to fix it by changing from Survey.SurveyModel to Survey.ReactSurveyModel